# LDAP Authentication with Windows Login Credentials

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, exchange-server

is it possible to authenticate against LDAP using the Windows Login Credentials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that LDAP server is an Active Directory backend, then yes, you can use Windows Login Credentials in the form of an AD account to authenticate.